# Where does rand() get its numbers from?

Tags: c++, random, iostream, cout

while working on a little project i thought i could generate "random" filenames with a little bit of code like this,

```
std::cout << "image"+rand()%255 << std::endl;
```

The outputs i got made no sense to me. They seem to be random parts of error messages.

for example this piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    while(1){
        std::cout << "image" + rand() % 255 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces gibberish like:

```
> ge
>
> n
>
>
> i
>
>
> ring too long
>
> U
>
>
>
>
>
> &
>
> n
> _
> o
>  string position
> e
> lid string position
> i
>
>
>
>
> U
> g
> invalid string position
>
> U
> ing position
>
>
> &
>
>
>
>
> ring position
> !
> n
>
> oo long
>
>
>
>
>
> o
> position
```

and a more complex piece of code in QtCreator (with the same cout rand endl statement in the main loop)

```
>    atform\mainwindow.cpp:210
>0
>I , null image received
>indow.cpp:210
>(QImage)
>dImage(QImage)
>, error: image not read from file!
> updatePlayerUI , null image received
>updatePlayerUI(QImage)
>ow.cpp:210
>dImage(QImage)
>ot chosen
>s not chosen
>og, error: image not read from file!
> was not chosen
>age not read from file!
>r: image not read from file!
>neDataPlatform\mainwindow.cpp:210
>error: image not read from file!
```

what is the reason for this?

Comment: FYI: rand() is no longer advised. Use the <random> library, instead.

Comment: This question is not well researched. You can't just take something really complicated that you don't understand and dump it all into a question. You should try to narrow the problem down and isolate it. For example, you could/should have tried `std::cout << "image"+10 << std::endl;` first to see if it does what you think before thinking about `rand()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of `"image"` is a `const char*`, you are doing pointer arithmetic here

```
"image" + rand() % 255
```

That is (potentially) undefined behavior because you are (likely) accessing outside the allocated memory for that string. To do what you are intending you want

```
std::cout << "image" << (rand() % 255) << std:endl
```

Or

```
std::cout << "image" + std::to_string(rand() % 255) << std:endl
```

Comment: Ehm or just `"image" << (rand() % 255)`, which would be far more sensible....

Comment: ok so the << just reads until it gets to a newline character or something?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, I'm just trying to make a point regarding why their original code did not work

Comment: @Lightness yeah i didnt use that code i just got curious when i saw the weird output

Comment: @CoryKramer: Sure, I'm just trying to make a point regarding making a better suggestion for fixing it :) The magic of string construction (and this effective `const char*`->`std::string` coercion) seems like too much for this particular question.

Comment: @maxx: No, I mean, your follow-up question doesn't make much sense. It seems you may fundamentally misunderstand the use of streams. Which book are you using?

Comment: (Hopefully Cory's updated answer will give you a "eureka" moment on that front, now that you can see chained `<<` operations on the stream)

Comment: i meant that it gets a pointer and then it apparently reads some amount of data from that address forward. I was guessing as to when it would end. I have not read about streams in a book.

Comment: @maxx: Oh right sorry I get ya. When you send a `char*` to a stream, it will eat up characters starting where that pointer's pointing and carry on until it hits a `'\0'` (NULL) character. And you should really read about things before you use them....!

Answer (score 9):

```
"image" + rand() % 255
```

This expression does not do what you think it does.

You think it means "take the result of the expression `rand() % 255`, convert it to a string, and concatenate it with the string `"image"`".

It actually means "take the pointer to the literal string `"image"` and increment that pointer by `rand() % 255` characters."

This results in undefined behavior when the result of `rand() % 255` is greater than 5 (out-of-bounds memory access).

In this particular case, your compiler is storing string literal values nearby each other in the generated program, so incrementing a pointer to a string literal is going to move through that memory and catch random strings.

The correct way to accomplish this would be:

```
std::cout << "image" << (rand() % 255) << std::endl;
```